# cname issue with hosted ecommerce

Tags: cname, shopify

Having a bit of an issue with a store that has just been set up with shopify. The problem is with cnaming the domain into the shopify subdomain. I have www working just fine so www.no1gadgetstore.co.uk cnames to no1gadgetstore.shopify.com. However, http://no1gadgetstore.co.uk does not resolve and I can't set up a cname for a non www record.

Does anybody have a simple solution to this, as everything I've come across so far is too complicated to even try.

Many thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2):

From one of our support guys:

> sounds like he just needs http://no1gadgetstore.co.uk to be a URL redirect to http://www.no1gadgetstore.co.uk - the CNAME should only be on the www. address.

For more on this, check out http://wiki.shopify.com/DNS